# How to access method in classes parent if it has a parent?

Tags: php, class, oop

Is it possible to check if a given class has a parent, and if so, then execute a method in the parent?  Below is my attempt, but as seen, will throw an error since `parentClass` doesn't have a parent.  Yes, I know that I can just change `parentClass::myMethod()` to just return `true` since it doesn't have a parent, but am curious how PHP handles this. Thanks

```
$obj=new childClass();
$rs=$obj->myMethod();

abstract class parentClass
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
        //This next line will throw an error since this class does not have a parent
        return (get_parent_class($this)?parent::myMethod():true);
    }
}

class childClass extends parentClass
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
        return (get_parent_class($this)?parent::myMethod():true);
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you want to attempt such perversions?

Comment: @tereško.  I know this implementation doesn't make sense, and am hypothetically asking whether it is possible.

Comment: You can get use reflectionclass to investigate a class. It might help. http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_parent_class` is already checking if the object has a parent. If it doesn't it returns `FALSE`. You aren't checking the return type, you are just assuming it returns the correct object and then trying to run `myMethod()` on it, which doesn't work because a bool returned which doesn't have `myMethod`.

Leaving aside that what you are attempting to do is seems like quite a bit of a code smell, you should first check if `get_parent_class` actually returned anything other than FALSE, and then run `method_exists` on the returned object to see if it has the `myMethod` method.

If both those things are satisfied you can then run `myMethod` and you won't get an error.

Comment: Thanks.  `return ((get_parent_class($this)===false)?parent::myMethod():true);` seems to work (also works with just `==`).  But why is `(get_parent_class($this)===false)` any different than `get_parent_class($this)`?  They are both `false`, no?

Comment: Apologies I missed the ternary operator in your first piece of code. The original way should work so long as get_parent_class returns either an object with myMethod or returns false. If it returns an object without myMethod it will still fail, so you should still check method_exists. 'get_parent_class($this)===false' equals true, so swap around the responses for the ternary operator.

Comment: It should work, but it doesn't.  This is a different question than my first, thus I accepted your original answer.  I am, however, still curious why it doesn't work.  Thoughts?

Comment: `$this` is always `childClass` even when called in `parentClass`. So the call in `parentClass` to `get_parent_class($this)` returns `'parentClass'`, rather than `false`. But when you call `parent.myMethod()` from within `parentClass` this fails since `parentClass` has no parent. Take out `$this` and just call `get_parent_class()`, this will default to the current object.